# NaN values after ComBat analysis on TCGA COAD RNAseq

Tags: r, combat

I have FPKM-UQ data from COAD-TCGA.

I generated an expression set of this data using:

```
> edata = log2(data + 1)
> edata[1:2,1:2]
      X01240896.3f3f.4bf9.9799.55c87bfacf36
1                                  8.540967
10                                13.528968
100                               16.296422
1000                              13.658199
10000                             15.143788
      X01ad5016.f691.4bca.82a0.910429d8d25b
1                                  9.886537
10                                16.719682
100                               17.212312
1000                              10.317842
10000                             13.166767
```

Row name is entrezid, and column names are case_ids.

The batch data provided by TCGA which indicates a total batch num = 42

```
> omics[1:5,]
                                      snf    boo order batch
X01240896.3f3f.4bf9.9799.55c87bfacf36   3 192807     1    22
X01ad5016.f691.4bca.82a0.910429d8d25b   2  82213     2     2
X01f493d4.229d.47a6.baa8.32a342c65d01   1 A08907     3    29
X022f39e9.57ee.4b2b.8b3a.8929e3d69a37   2 A16S13     4    32
X02f9668c.71e6.485f.88b1.b37dc8bdd2ab   3 102113     5     7
> batch = omics$batch
> batch
  [1] 22  2 29 32  7  1  8  8  7 41 26 14 26 26  1  5 22  5 15 18 28 12 12  8 19
 [26] 13 38  5 27  7 41  1 22 26 28 22 33 14 13  8 10 13 11 17  5 38  5  7  7 31
 [51] 22 42 11  8  7 17 15 17 12 17  2 19  2 12 18 14 22 11 21 15 17 17 33 15 19
 [76] 15  6  1 10 11  2 28 36 17  9 15 12 17 15 10  6  8 13 25 11 15  1 13 24  8
[101] 13 15 17  8  2 22 17 11 13 37 19 38 13 19  5 16  5  5 22 35 35 19 13 17 22
[126]  7  8  8 41 39 14  6 19 18 38 22 14 30 19 24 11 14 13 16  7 13  8 22 12  8
[151] 22 17  2 40 13 35 15  5 24 19 41 22 22 19 17  8 13 33 10 17 29 12  9 11 24
[176] 27  5 14  7 25 13 35  9 18 16 13 31 25 18 10 35 18 14 33  5 19 17  8 11 11
[201] 42  7 10  8 39 19  8  7 11 19 31 35 28 36 13 37 10 38  3 18 13 34 39 13  3
[226] 40 31 17 19 26  7 19 12 22 19 17 12 17 13 12 28 33 37 17 35 18 40 13 20 35
[251] 17  6 15 14 12 27  5 41 31 41 18 21 19 17 40  8 41  2  5 15  5 15 15  5 39
[276]  1 22 33 13 17  7 11 15  3  7 38 15  7 14 14 22 31 14 18  3 19  7  9  6  5
[301] 22  8 11  1 13 10 19  8 14 15  6 32  1  2 19  4  5 13 18 42 11 17  8 36 19
[326] 15 22 28 15  8 11  8 15 38 19 39  7 11 42 23  5  1 22 17 35 13 40 25  7 41
[351] 38  5  8 19 31  6 38  8 36  4 15 15  7 12 22 38 29 35 15  2 10  2 19 15 25
[376]  5 39 30 19 18 15 10 10 33  1 19 32 19 19 15 20 15  7 22 35 22 30 14 12 16
[401] 21 13 15 18  7  5  6 31 12  7 15 32 33 18 14 15 15 26 31  1 14 19 17 18  1
[426]  5 10 32
```

Unfortunately, when I run the ComBat analysis it generates all NANs, and no values:

```
> modcombat = model.matrix(~1, data=omics)
> combat_edata = ComBat(dat=edata, batch=batch, mod=modcombat, par.prior=TRUE, prior.plots=FALSE)
> combat_edata[1:5,1:2]
      X01240896.3f3f.4bf9.9799.55c87bfacf36
1                                       NaN
10                                      NaN
100                                     NaN
1000                                    NaN
10000                                   NaN
      X01ad5016.f691.4bca.82a0.910429d8d25b
1                                       NaN
10                                      NaN
100                                     NaN
1000                                    NaN
10000                                   NaN
```

Comment: What happens if you make `batch` a factor?

Comment: So when I normalize the data first by mean, then perform the log2 conversion, the batch correction works.

Comment: Stipulating batch as factor generates the same NAN result. I'm thinking that maybe it wasn't close enough to a normal distribution without the mean normalization, so it wasn't able to calculate the correction?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for your question and welcome to Bioinformatics Stack Exchange. I have changed your title to be more specific and match the question that you have asked. Having specific questions makes it more likely that people will be able to answer your problem (or be interested in answering it), and some people won't click through if they see a question that has a vague title.

Comment: It's just interesting because the data is supposedly already normalized between samples using FPKM-UQ. So I'm not clear why the additional mean normalization is necessary. In particular, I need to do something like: data <- standardNormalization(data) to scale the mean at 0 w/ stdev @ 1, then log2(data + 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I might know what the problem is.

I plotted the log2 corrected values, and the distribution may not be normal because of the 0 values present in RNASeq data. If I understand correctly, this data is actually missing, whereas with my current analysis it is viewed by R as an actual value of 0. So either the missing data needs to be imputed, or the data needs to be scaled and normalized to mean of 0, then subsequently log2 transformed.

```
> data <- standardNormalization(data)
> data <- log2(data + 1)
> combat_data = ComBat(dat=data, batch=batch, mod=modcombat, par.prior=TRUE, prior.plots=FALSE)
> combat_data[1:5,1:2]
          X01240896.3f3f.4bf9.9799.55c87bfacf36
100507661                           -0.13857428
57103                               -0.06700506
22838                                0.16295096
55567                               -0.13579991
6147                                 1.64990772
          X01ad5016.f691.4bca.82a0.910429d8d25b
100507661                           -0.13789534
57103                               -0.06210232
22838                                0.01546224
55567                               -0.13443289
6147                                 1.48473072
```